# Dockerfile_Django REST_ERROR _Cannot uninstall 'six'. It is a distutils installed

Tags: python, django, docker, dockerfile

Docker Django REST API Build stalled with Error

```
Cannot uninstall 'six'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.
```

Have updated the complete stack trace / log here - https://github.com/digital-cognition-co-in/Django_REST_API_with_OpenCV_on_HEROKU

[image]

my Dockerfile -

```
#
FROM ubuntu:xenial

RUN apt-get update 

RUN apt-get install -y python3 # install python3

RUN apt-get install -y python-pip python-dev build-essential

# Make and Change to DIR - dck1 (MKDIR + WORKDIR)
#
COPY ./REST_CV /usr/src/rest_api/
WORKDIR /usr/src/rest_api/
#
RUN ls
#
RUN pwd
# Docker has default "sh" Shell and Conda prefers a "bash" shell 
#
#RUN ["/bin/bash", "-c", " git clone https://github.com/digital-cognition-co-in/Statistical-Model-Management-Framework"]
# Above for Testing only 

# Install CURL
RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends vim nano git wget curl
# Install miniconda to /miniconda
RUN curl -LO http://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh
RUN bash Miniconda-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -p /miniconda -b
RUN ls ## Will Show file == Miniconda-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh
RUN rm Miniconda-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh
RUN ls ## To check we have removed file == Miniconda-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh
ENV PATH=/miniconda/bin:${PATH}
RUN conda update -y conda
#
#
RUN ["/bin/bash", "-c", "conda create -n docker_opencv_venv python=3.5"]
RUN ["/bin/bash", "-c", "source activate docker_opencv_venv"]
#
#COPY ./requirements.txt /usr/src/rest_api/requirements.txt ## If we want to Copy only a Single File
#
#RUN find requirements.txt ## If we want to "find" a file within same DIR 
#
#RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt 
### We want the PACKAGES to be CACHED on the Docker DIR
#
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r /usr/src/rest_api/requirements.txt
#
EXPOSE 8000
#
RUN ls
RUN pwd
#
CMD ["python", "manage.py", "migrate"]
#
# Error --- python: can't open file 'manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
#
CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
#
```

As asked by Jerin am posting my Dockerfile above .

Comment: post your Dockerfile/docker-compose file

Comment: Hey Jerin - added my Dockerfile - also upvoted your comment - thanks

Comment: replace `RUN pip install -r /usr/src/rest_api/requirements.txt` with `RUN pip install -r /usr/src/rest_api/requirements.txt --ignore-installed six` . I think it would solve the issue

Comment: any update ? @Rohit

Comment: Update - When installing the CONDA VENV inside a DOCKER Image - to run a Custom Env for Django , ensure you dont include same Packages within your *requirements.txt* file as you would be installing by default when creating a CONDA venv.  @rohitsakala